# Visual Studio 2019 SLN Out of Date

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm brand new to using VS, so this is almost certainly something I screwed up, but I can't find a solution/don't know what to ask Google.

When I double-click my sln file, it opens an outdated version in VS. Like, I recognize the files and organization and things from earlier, but I've done hours of work since then.

When I go into the folder, there's all the new files and updated files with updated file names, but I can't get the sln file to load those. I tried building and rebuilding, but it errors out because it can't find a file - a file that doesn't exist anymore because it's been renamed and many changes have happened.

I tried renaming the file in Solution Explorer from the old name to the new name, thinking that might help it find the new files, but it can't do that because it "could not find file" - again, because that one doesn't exist anymore either because it's been renamed and changed a lot.

Please help me get this fixed, and if anyone can tell me how I screwed this up, that would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: Did you try to double-click the `.sln` file in the folder? Is it possible that the `.sln` file was over-written by an older version - if that happened you will need to rebuild the solution.

Comment: Yes I double clicked. I tried rebuilding, that's when I got the first "file not found" error mentioned.

Comment: If you started a new solution and added the files to it, how can they not be found?

Comment: I didn't start a new solution and add files to it. I opened the one that was already created and the files weren't there.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `.sln` file was over-written by an older version,
or just that it wasn't saved when Visual Studio was closed (or crashed).

If you are getting references to files that do not exist and are not visible
in the Visual Studio interface, you may use this strong method:

- Close Visual Studio
- Open the project file `.vcxproj` file in a text editor
- Search for the names of these files and delete.
  Be careful to delete the entire XML tag, which might look something like:

  ```
  <ClCompile Include="filename.c">
    <AdditionalOptions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug AMD64|Win32'"> /J  /Wp64 /GS-   /Wp64 /GS- </AdditionalOptions>
    <AdditionalOptions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug AMD64|x64'"> /J  /Wp64 /GS-   /Wp64 /GS- </AdditionalOptions>
  </ClCompile>
  ```
- Save the project file and open the Visual Studio solution.

Be careful to take backups of the files before starting.

Comment: I did that, and it no longer loaded the old files, and still didn't load the ones I wanted. Was I meant to add in those tags with the files I want?

Comment: Adding the files is done by the user interface. It's too complicated to do by hand.

Comment: Well... I'd made a copy of the whole folder, just in case, then somehow managed to delete the original, but thought nbd I have the copy, but apparently copying a folder no longer also copies the contents -- which is incredibly stupid -- so... I have to start all over. Thanks for trying to help.